# Looking for a webserver runnable without compilation on solaris for purely statical content?

Tags: web, webserver, multiplatform, solaris-10

I don't know how to turn the question so that it can have a single response. Basically I own a static internet website (pure rest/json/javascript) that I need to be served, and I am looking for an http server where I could just put the files and have it up and working.

I am running on solaris with no administration rights, so I'd rather if it was easy to install with no compilation, so basically I think an http server written in java would perfectly fit.

I think Apache would have been a perfect choice, and it is already installed on solaris, but I don't have the administration privileges I would need to activate it.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

- Wrap the static website in a WAR archive (I just unpackaged and repackaged the sample.war they provide as a demo for tomcat)
- Download a version of tomcat appropriated for the installed version of java and deploy the war into it.

Not very elegant nor performant, but does the job. I am staying with this for the time being.